# SSDT goes into not responding when checking new SSRS query using a linked server

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-data-tools

This particular SSRS query that uses a linked server from the main database takes VS SSDT into a "Not responding" state when refreshing the fields. All other SSRS queries using the same main database only work fine, so I'm assuming there's a permission issue along the way executing DDL on the linked server. The issue is that running a DDL on the linked server from my account on SSMS works fine. So I have permissions. The data source on the report is also using my account doing windows authentication. Anyone knows what user SSRS impersonates to execute the DDL on a linked server?

Thank you

Comment: I'm not sure that DDL has anything to do with your issue. DDL - data definition language, these are the queries that are creating/altering objects. I don't see why would you need DDL to refresh the fields in SSRS. Several things you can try to troubleshoot: 1) run profile  and see what's going on; 2) re-create the object in other database, without data and check if the issue still remain; 3) try other object from the same database and then do refresh to check that it works with other objects

Comment: Dmitrij, SSRS has to verify the query is correct and all referenced columns and tables exist. That's why I assume it uses DDL.

Comment: DDL when you create or change something. Checking if the object exist or checking it's structure can be made different ways but probably not by using DDL statements. Normally it's done by querying system tables and getting metadata from there.